# Import issue: Missing columns values from CSV file

Tags: mysql, import, ubuntu, mysql-5.7

I have a problem with the importing of a  CSV file to my table in MySQL. The values (3) of the columns `(var1, var2, dates)` are not loading, as shown in the image below:

[image]

First I created the table,

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
    var1 INT NOT NULL,
    var2 INT NOT NULL,
    dates DATE NOT NULL
);
```

After that, I imported the data to the table:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/task.csv' 
INTO TABLE table1 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
       OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
       ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

I am using an Ubuntu terminal.

Comment: Is there other data in the file that *is* being imported? (you specify three columns, but the table only has 4 columns, and you wouldn't expect `id` to come from the file. Some people pare out information to simplify a problem or to eliminate confidential info; sometimes, that "simplifies" critical info out of the question). Also, you have double-checked that the file is formatted as you expect, and that the line termination characters are what you expect? Are you getting as many rows with the zero values shown as are supposed to be in the file?

Comment: Yes, it is just 4 columns the id is appearing normally, Yes the file is formatted I double checked it. It is just showing zeros is not showing the real values. - ........"the line termination characters are what you expect?".....this I do not know.

Comment: this refers to the fact that EOL on Windows is two characters, ASCII 13 and 10 (carriage return and line feed, CRLF, etc.) As I recall, Unix systems (including Linux) use ASCII 13 only. You specified the line ending as `\n` - if this file was generated on a Windows system, the terminator should probably be `\n\r` (as best I recall).

Answer (score 0):

Specify the column list so you won't include `id`.  Add this after then `IGNORE` clause:

```
(var1, var2, dates)
```